# Tree diagrams in CGEL

Tags: syntax-trees, x-bar-theory, nominals

I have a question about this tree diagram in The Cambridge Grammar of The English Language (by Huddleston and Pullum):

[image]

Please see the tree diagram in the red box of the nominal `preposterous salary from Lloyds`. (In CGEL, a nominal corresponds to N' in the X bar theory, and is written in the tree diagram as 'Nom'.)

### Question

**In [11], why does `preposterous salary` form the first nominal and then combine with the complement `from Lloyds` to form the second nominal (the higher one in the tree)? Shouldn't `salary from Lloyds` form a first nominal and then combine with `preposterous` to form a second one?**

For comparison, here's another tree diagram in CGEL:
[image]
In [5a], `old man` forms a nominal as does `preposterous salary`, but unlike in [11], there's no complement of `man`.

Here's another diagram in CGEL:
[image]
Here, the nominal `careful analysis of the issues` contains the same tree structure not as [5a] but as [11]. And I think that's because the noun `analysis` is followed by the complement `of the issues`. Hence the question.

Comment: I'd consider "from Lloyds" to be an adjunct, not a complement/argument.

Comment: @curiousdannii Come to think of it, I also wonder why CGEL calls it a complement. Might this be a typo or even an error on the part of CGEL? This is not listed as such here: http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/cgelerrata.html

Comment: I'm not really familiar with their syntax tree model, but it does say "Head: Nom" for that phrase, so doesn't that mean it does form a nominal?

Comment: @curiousdannii "Head: Nom" corresponds to N' in the X-bar tree. There are two things about CGEL's tree. 1. They have "Head: N --- _salary_" instead of "Head: Nom --- Head: N --- _salary_", for simplicity. 2. They use the term Mod (modifier) instead of adjunct. So the question boils down to why _from Lloyds_ is a sister to "Head: Nom" and a daughter to "Head: Nom" when it's complement. But if it really is an adjunct as you say, this is merely using the wrong notation 'Comp: PP' instead of using 'Mod: PP' (meaning 'adjunct') at the top of the triangle over _from Lloyds_, I guess. Am I right?

Comment: Try replacing "salary from Lloyds" with the indefinite pronoun "one", to see whether it is a constituent.  Only constituents can be antecedents.

Comment: @GregLee I have no problem with _even all the preposterous one that Bill gets_, do you?

Comment: If you mean that the antecedent of "one" may be "salary from Lloyds", then no, I don't have a problem with that.  And that was my point.  The CGEL structure is mistaken, since "from Lloyds" is actually a complement of "salary", not "preposterous salary".

Comment: @GregLee So you disagree with curiousdannii that the PP is adjunct?

Comment: @JK2 I have no opinion about whether the PP is a complement or an adjunct.  I called it a complement just out of deference to the CGEL treatment.

Comment: @JK2 I've cracked it, thanks to John Payne. He tells me that the choice of preposition "from" was determined by the head noun "salary". It could not, for example, naturally be replaced in this context by "of", "out of", etc. For this reason the PP "from Lloyds" was deemed to be a complement, not a modifier. Thus the original is in fact correct.

Comment: @BillJ Silly us, looking like traditional grammarians at the noun dependent  instead of the Head preposition! However, I still find it incredibly odd to have a noun with a Complement that does not occur within its own immediate phrase! Does it not seem odd to you?

Comment: @Araucaria-him Somehow, I didn't get any notification of the recent comments...until your last comment. Just like you said in your last comment, I believe that what BillJ said John Payne said, if anything, would only make my original question the more relevant, rather than solve it. That is, the red box of tree diagram [11] should be just like that of [52a].

Comment: [from Lloyds] is most likely a complement of [salary] - agnostic on this so far - but the tree structure in CGEL is wrong. If it's [the [NP preposterous salary][PP from Lloyds]], how would you analyze e.g. *the absolutely preposterous salary from Lloyds* or *the absolutely preposterous 300k salary from Lloyds*?

Comment: @AlexB. I agree with you. And most likely, so would Araucaria. It's not clear from what BillJ said, whether John Payne did confirm that the tree diagram is correct.

Comment: @BillJ What do you exactly mean "the original is in fact correct"? Do you mean that the original tree diagram is correct? If so, is that something John Payne himself confirmed? Is it your own opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always wondered about this tree too. In particular, I wondered why *from Lloyds* would be a complement. And so I asked Geoff Pullum, who replied that he thinks that *salary* doesn't take complements. In other words, it's a mistake.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure it is a mistake. Re 52: "Analysis" selects (licenses) an _of_ PP, and thus "of the issued" is a complement of "analysis". Re 11: On the other hand, "salary" does not select "from", and thus the PP "from Lloyds" is a complement in (and thus part of) the nominal "preposterous salary from Lloyds". PPs like this are complements, not modifiers, the latter typically consisting of those PPs with a locative ot temporal meaning.

Comment: The important point I was making in my last comment is that _from_ PPs function as complements, not modifiers, so I think GKP is mistaken.

Comment: @BillJ Complements are licensed by the head of the phrase, so *from* PPs may be either modifiers or complements, depending on the head. *Arrival*, for instances takes a *from* PP complement (e.g., *their arrival from Bethlehem*), while *coffee* (e.g., *that coffee from yesterday*) doesn't.

Comment: That's a good thought, but if you start assigning functions to constituents based on the function of an anaphorically related gap, you're quickly going to run into all sorts of problem. For instance it would make *BillJ* in *BillJ is the user I met online* an object, which simply won't do.

Comment: Does Geoff Pullum still believe that there is any meaningful distinction to be made between complements and modifiers when it comes to the *of*-PPs which occur after nouns within nominals?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't very clear. I was muddying the water by talking about *of*-PPs there. What I was trying to ask was whether Geoff feels there is really any difference in cases like *salary from Lloyds* between complements and adjuncts? The reason I ask is because of this, in particular section 4.0 (p.805) : [Anaphoric one and its implications](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/Anaphoric_One.pdf). Here Geoff et al seem to suggest there isn't any principled syntactic distinction to be made. (That is if I understood the paper and that section correctly, of course!).

Comment: @BrettReynolds Looking at this again. I wonder if we could say it's a complement because "from Lloyds" tells us the source of the salary (the giver) and source PPs can be complements: see CGEL p260 'Possession'. Also, "from Lloyds" is a preposed element: the basic order would be "the preposterous salary [that Bill gets from Lloyds]", where "preposterous salary" is direct object and the PP "from Lloyds" is complement of "get", which licenses it.

Comment: @BillJ "Bill gets his salary from Lloyds from Lloyds, of course."  --> seems to show that the *from Lloyds* is dependent of *salary*, not *gets* in the original example, I think.

Comment: I'm 99.9% certain that RDH intended it to be labelled as a complement not a modifier .I can't believe he'd make such a error. Unfortunately, we cannot ask him now.

Comment: @BillJ Yes, may be. [Btw, I think in a book that big, there's going to be the very odd error about. There's thousands of examples analysed, so even taking a 99.9% confidence rate that would  amount to a few errors here and there!]

Comment: We could say that in the r/c, "proposterous salary" is direct object of "gets" and "from Lloyds" is complement of "gets", not modifier of "salary". A source complement, per CGEL.

Comment: @BillJ I don't think we could. Two reasons: first, it would be a much bigger error in terms of the tree diagram that the minor putative original one (as it should be in the relative clause branch of the tree). Second: while clause adjuncts can be preposed to the position before the subordinator, the same is not true of the complements of verbs. **The man from the fridge that took the beer*, for example.

Comment: @BillJ I think a third view is that this is one of these situations where the parsing is ambiguous (i.e. it could be either [preposterous] [salary from Lloyds] or, alternatively [preposterous salary] [from Lloyds] - where I've simplified the bracketing a lot.) and it makes virtually no discernible difference to the meaning.

Comment: @BillJ Maybe a better example would be **The man from Lloyds that gets his salary.* What do you think?

Comment: Complement preposing is possible, e.g. "Most of it she had written herself" / "I said I'd pay for it and pay for it I will".

Comment: You said "the same is not true of the complements of verbs". Never mind, this is getting silly. I'm sticking to my claim (and RDH's) that "from Lloyds" is a complement.

Comment: @BillJ Well, I said "while clause adjuncts can be preposed **to the position before the subordinator**, the same is not true of the complements of verbs."! I'm not necessarily averse to the given  analysis, apart from that I'm not sure it's even possible in RDH's CGEL grammar for the head noun in a nominal to have a modifier it's immediate phrase and then to take another phrase within the nominal as a complement. That seems extremely odd.

Comment: @BillJ I think it's an editing error. RDH/someone originally went for [**MODIFIER/adj:** preposterous [**HEAD/nom:** salary from Lloyds]] and wanted to change it to [**HEAD/nom:** preposterous salary [**MODIFIER/preposition phrase:** from Lloyds]] but the *Complement* label didn't get changed. The two intended original alternatives would both be fine, of course.

Comment: @BillJ  Should read "modifier *in* its immediate phrase", sorry.

Comment: I've cracked it, thanks to John Payne. He tells me that the choice of preposition "from" was determined by the head noun "salary". It could not, for example, naturally be replaced in this context by "of", "out of", etc. For this reason the PP "from Lloyds" was deemed to be a complement, not a modifier.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks for confirming that with John Payne. I wonder if GPK would agree, though.

Comment: @BillJ Also, see my comment to Araucaria above.